# Do there exist ideas which are true beyond axiom systems?

Tags: logic, principle-of-non-contradiction

I find that sometimes there are many systems in which one could prove/ describe a single idea given in Mathematics. This made me wonder, is the thing we are proving actually true beyond the proof tools themself in some sense(*)? Like consider Russel's Set theory, some of the idea we could say in that about Sets still could be said when ZFC came. So, does this mean that those statements were like a truth of life more fundamental than Naive Set theory itself?

If there is some sense in what I said above, would there be a way to pre-emptively identify these fundamental truths of life other than seeing that they can be still shown when we remove any apparent contradictions in our foundations?(the second requires actually finding contradictions)

Comment: In mathematics, we prove *theorems* starting from axioms and using logical rules. Outside mathematics, we have empirical fact whose knowledge is not based on "proof"; and we have other beliefs: art, society, religion.

Comment: I understand but how does that relate to my question exactly ? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: If the question is about "ideas", in what sense are you asserting that "ideas are true"? Is the idea of "dog" true?

Comment: I guess ideas relating to physical ideas we want to formalise through mathematics @Mauro ALLEGRANZA. For example the idea of having a set, taking its union intersection etc. I'm not quite sure about the idea of the dog. I'll think and reply

Comment: Any truth expressed in language contains implicit assumptions. An axiom systems is just an attempt to formalize some of those assumptions.

Comment: Indeed per your platonism penchant as expressed by Godel, there's fundamental truth out there than set theory which human mind may not be able to conceive exhaustively, so even ZFC turns out to be inconsistent it has nothing to do with math itself which under intuitionism it would be a much more serious problem as foundation of the whole math...

Comment: On the underlying intuitions and heuristic principles that feed ZFC set theory and its extensions see a nice expose by Maddy, [Believing the axioms I](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/belaxioms1.pdf) and [II](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/belaxioms2.pdf). We cannot identify those  truths "pre-emptively" because they are subtle, complex, only vaguely perceived until suitable conceptual apparatus is developed and correlated with prior knowledge, etc. Godel's results can be interpreted as implying that the process of formulating them is inexhaustible in principle.

Comment: But yes, the sources of our mathematical theories and concepts must be human language and experience. We have some basic "intuitions" about collections of objects and parts of collections and we analyze and discuss them. At some point we find useful to try to manage them rigorously with mathematics. But then we have several related but different approaches: [Set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/), [Type theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/), [Mereology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/).